# fs.writeFileSnyc/fs.writeFile writes a corrupted file

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, google-drive-api

I'm calling Google Drive's download API and then I want to write the downloaded file locally using `fs.writeFile` or `fs.writeFileSync`. Here's what I'm doing:

```
    const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile)
    const file_from_google = await axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${id}?alt=media`,
            {headers: 
                {'Authorization': `Bearer ${someToken}`},                        
            },)
    const fullPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'downloads','testFile.docx')
    writeFile(fullPath, file_from_google.data)
```

While it does create the file for me in the specified directory, the file is corrupted regardless of doing `writeFile` or `writeFileSync`. I've also tried directly using `fs.writeFileSync` instead of promisifying it. Almost every time I get a corrupted file larger than the original file size. Can someone give me an idea what's a good way to get the downloaded file correctly written on the directory?

Comment: Unimportant side note, you can use `fs.promises.writeFile` instead of having to do `util.promisify`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Is `fs.promises.writeFile` an agreed up way it's going to be going forward in node.js.  I've seen `require('fs/promises')` too and discussion about which way to do it.

Comment: @jfriend00 fs/promises won't happen - it might be at `@nodejs/fs` at some point, fs.promises is how things are looking so far so it's a fair bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` option to `axios.get`

```
const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile)
const file_from_google = await axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${id}?alt=media`,
        {responseType: 'arraybuffer, headers: 
            {'Authorization': `Bearer ${someToken}`},                        
        },)
const fullPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'downloads','testFile.docx')
writeFile(fullPath, file_from_google.data)
```