# download image from POST api response in Node js

Tags: node.js

I have a simple code.

```js
axios.post(MY_URL).then((res)=>{
  console.log(res);
});
```

and it is the console output.

```
{
  ...
  data: '�PNG\r\n' +
    '\x1A\n' +
    `\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00�\x00\x00\x00(\b\x06\x00\x00\x00\x1C�\x03�\x00\x00\x04vIDATx��[aD]Q\x1C?�'��L���L��c2�Cҗ�d2�'O2�L\x1F\x12iӇɾ�$31��3���<32O��d�0ӗ�d�'-y��c�����=��w�y���?~��?�{���9���1��)�h��~\x10\b\x01��E c\x11�X\x042��\x1A�Wr\x18�\x06��E�"c���Xd,\x02\x19���\x15�Lq�\x04���\x1C\\��\x06�眯8�9_p> c�\x1B��\x1A)濺�+�upnib� �\x04\x03�YΓ�θd���5UB�)͘nr~�\x00K9\x19�'������L�\x0FT�:Ê�tq\x1Ej�u�y\x00\x14q\x052V8��2��\x14/.�U�в�\f�\x15�<��&�\x1C���BG|���䬡�=��2�O)~�s\x1Ci<��ű\x13�\x1E��F�V8\x1BiW�\x7F\x18�\x13�����*��\x1F�\x18'~\t�ǐ�G\x0F\x1D2V\x19�(�2�\x03�x��Y����I��k�\x1CǜQΌ���@�\x14�\x01\x03���rh�$cY�c��z�E\r/DQb��vy��7�ɡ��\x1B�q�]\f��@���ւ�\x17��F7��(v�n�Q$��h'�@�:\x1Fc��r\x12\rX�\x0B�����@�H�7g��\x7F\x1C�ɱ7�f�\x0B���\\��\x00˥�\x11�B�3�����P \x1C�eBWu~fQ\x03�\x1E�,���\x1A�X*���b\x1C�O\x1Dj����\x19�/0\x1D\x19�'Z\x15�p��]���\b�ץ0�J��e-����v���\x1Fb����\x0F~R!�u)~ϰF��8����\x1C�2��\x12~熈���cTs���hA�2f�I�~�t\x02�\x119��A�\x0Eg�$c�D���9���4�����\x14��(pއs6�瘟�MW\x0EYC���Xvv��\n` +
    "h|�bw\x15��1�7\x17�I7��E����l���\x0F\x11M\x1EbS�\x1D�>Uh\x16���%�kx��5�5��z\x1C\x19�\x07�.�ص�1�bc\x1E�\x1B1\x18ǰ&�zh�����ܓ�|`��B�-j��H.hn+b:�V�`\x1CI��\x0F;���k�*��'cy�\x152�X�0�gjJ̑\x04\x16Xq!U�|]�\x17?W� c��\x03�hq\x17'�-v\x04��9�^9�\bPC�7(��%n\x15\x19#��L���B�|\x1E�X��e���ӷ���wi&�I\x17:\b\r�LT`���Lf�\x03�kEв*r��Ki!��-ʥ\x04a�,�ɰ�F�%�]j\x0BX\x03c��+�nH��6��#�ܮ�\x15?�vL�W��57\x05\x19�D3�\x0B%\x1E\x1A�Y�����f��z��q,��7\x15�.�R��+$u�s3��J����aj�C\x0E�\x01�\t�\x1A���E\r\x19�(\x0Fʖ����ٷAU3��K�\r�\x01p�\tW�<�\n" +
    ']�!lH�r�|\x13z�#�W�;\t7����(+���d,\x85\x02\x19�@�"��XDb��\x0B?\x7F�@\x1F["�\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND�B`�'
}
```

I know it is a PNG Image but I don't know how to download it.

How can I download it with Node.js?

Comment: What do you hope the output will be when you print it to console? Has the image been downloaded locally?

Comment: @Isolated I hope to download the image on my disk.

Comment: You mean save the png payload locally into a file ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee yes I want to save the png using that payload.

Comment: @kyun I'd suggest having a look here: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/download-files-images-with-axios-in-node-js. You're essentially missing a step between downloading the file and persisting it (in addition to not using a stream).

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51638033/7177029